# Apache persists on not wanting to redirect to https

Tags: apache-2.4, django, 301-redirect

I know many people have ask similar not to say the same question before:

**How can I redirect http to https (Using Apache)?/Why does it not do so?**

There is even a "code" snippet on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) page of HTTP 301 status code that redirects to https.

But after hours of searching I tried many different methods out of with only one is working:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="https://example.org">
```

as a default page at `/var/www/html/index.html`

Even though it successfully redirects it is more than ugly and also not really liked by search engines and increases loading time.

To get us all on one level [this](http://pastebin.com/2MEpvVzB)
 is my Apache configuration. I also use Django in combination with Apache in case that has any relevance.

So here is a listing of all my attempts:

1. Use another VirtualHost

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       Redirect permanent / https://example.org/
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Use a rewrite that redirect everything that not connects on port 443 to the corresponding https page:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
   RewriteRule ^(/(.*))?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`
   ```
3. Use the implementation mentioned from Wikipedia:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R,L]
   ```

I tried these options (where it made sense) in both `apache2.conf` and `.htaccess` files. Obviously with no success. Weirdly enough when I visit example.org and then after it has loaded manually type example.org/# the last two methods worked. I have tried also with only example.org/ and the same procedure but without #. But that does not work.

What other options are there (for a 301-Redirect)? Why does this not work? And if it possible: How can I modify it to get it working?

Comment: if you just do a simple search of this site you would find lots of answers to your question.

Comment: The redirect in your attemp 1 should work. Don't use rewrite rules for such a task. Did you restart your apache server to read the new configuration?

Comment: @Hanginoninquietdesperation Obviously I have researched quite a lot and tried out several methods. If you know of any method other than I mentioned your help is welcome. In addition I would not have asked that question (_because_ there were so many similar ones) if I had not yet tried the solutions in those questions.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your answer since those errors could be made easily. I went even as far as restarting the whole machine or purposely make a wrong config only to check if the configuration file was loaded. But why is rewrite a bad choice? Many resources (even Wikipedia) recommend this way of configuring a redirect to https.

Comment: Well, the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) state "...`mod_rewrite` should be considered a last resort...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first redirect should work, if it doesn't don't think too hard, then you are simply not "landing" in that virtualhost/server/config, if you have more *:80 virtualhosts make sure they all have the `ServerName` directive with their own name, otherwise Apache won't know where to deliver the requests. To make sure you have configured your virtualhosts correctly you can type:

```
apachectl -S
```

...and make sure no virtualhosts have the same name (or none), otherwise the first match wins.

Also, try to connect locally, try against the ip directly, and use a non-caching browser to make sure you are seeing the correct response and not cached responses, or your name resolution is pointing to other server. As in:

```
curl -I -H"Host:myserver.example.com" http://192.168.1.10/
```

Briefly
In virtualhost this is enough:

```
Redirect / https://myserver.example.com/
```

Comment: As you were pointing out: There was indeed another virtualhost. Since I use Apache only for ssl negotiation I was not _too_ bothered with configuration and did not see that in sites-enabled there was a default configuration which probably caused the problem.